# Using only base python count student per course from a csv file (no other dictionaries except python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Initial CSV file has these columns and rows

> enroll_code,student_id
>
> 10030,55000
>
> 10030,55804
>
> 10250,55804
>
> 10510,55000

## After reading the csv file the data list becomes a list of sublists

```
import csv
data=[]
with open('C:/Users/Taha/Downloads/Data.csv','r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    data=list(reader)
    print(data)

csvFile.close()
```

## Output of the above code gives this as data.

```
data=[['enroll_code', 'student_id'], ['10030', '55000'], ['10030', '55804'], ['10250', '55804'], ['10510', '55000']]
```

## The result I need is

> 10030: 2
>
> 10250: 1
>
> 10510: 1

How do I convert it into a dictionary and have the key 10030 represent and count both student_id

## When I do:

```
import csv
data={}
with open('C:/Users/Taha/Downloads/Data.csv','r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    data=dict(reader)
    print(data)

csvFile.close()
```

It only gives output: `{'enroll_code': 'student_id'}`

What I need is a way for python to count of number of occurences on the enroll_code, lets say if there were a thausand entries in the CSV file and enroll_code and student_id were repeated throughout the CSV file, how do I code it to get the required result.

## Basically I want to code it in base python what the Code below would yield

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.gourpby('enroll_code').count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most straightforward way that comes to mind is simply going over your items and "counting" them into a dictionary

assuming you already did

```
data=list(reader)
```

you can then do:

```
result = {}
for item in data[1:]:
    if item[0] not in result :
        result [item[0]] = 1
    else:
        result [item[0]] += 1
```

we are going over your data item by item, skipping the header (thats why we have the `data[1:]` part), checking if the item is in the dictionary and if it isnt we add it with the count of 1, otherwise we increment the current count

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any external library, you can achieve the desired result using `.get`:

```
data=[['enroll_code', 'student_id'], ['10030', '55000'], ['10030', '55804'], ['10250', '55804'], ['10510', '55000']]


dct = {}

for x in data[1:]:
    dct[x[0]] = dct.get(x[0], 0) + 1

print(dct)
```

**output:**

> `{'10030': 2, '10250': 1, '10510': 1}`

`.get` returns the value of key (`x[0]`) if the key is in the dictionary, otherwise returns 0. Then we sum 1 to this value (`x[0]`'s value or 0) and assign the new value to the same key.
Here's a link to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) on `.get` and other dictionary's methods

Comment: I always forget the `dict.get`, this is very neat

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
with open('C:/Users/Taha/Downloads/Data.csv') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    next(reader)   #Skip Header. 
    for row in reader:
        result[row[0]] += 1
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {
    '10250': 1, 
    '10510': 1, 
    '10030': 2
    })
```

Comment: I'm not sure about what user meant with `no other dictionaries except python`. If he's OK with importing collections, I think this is the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
import csv

with open('C:/Users/Taha/Downloads/Data.csv') as f:
    enroll_count = {}
    reader = csv.reader(f)    
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        code = row[0]
        if code in enroll_count:
            enroll_count[code] += 1
        else:
            enroll_count[code] = 1
    print(enroll_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
data=pd.DataFrame([['10030', '55000'], ['10030', '55804'], ['10250', '55804'], ['10510', '55000']],columns=['enroll_code', 'student_id'])
dict(data.groupby('enroll_code').count())
```